# A callback for publish method in Autobahn?

Tags: callback, publish-subscribe, autobahn

I wonder why there is no callback defined on the publish method in AutobahnJS? I think it would be useful for the client who tries to publish something to know whether their publish call succeeded or not and react accordingly. I wonder if other frameworks that support pub/sub have such a callback for publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define "success" for a publish? Depending on that, PubSub will get very different. Today, WAMP PubSub is a Best-Effort service. WAMPv2 might get other QoS levels in addition.

Comment: Well, I would probably define it successful if the message was actually sent to any subscribers. I mean it might be sent, but it never gets anywhere, if there are no subscribers at all.

Comment: This will require waiting for acknowledge from all subscribers that were subscribed at the time of publish before acknowledging the publish. What if 1 dispatch fails, but the other succeeded? (=> transactional messaging). What if a subscriber is currently disconnected? (=> persistent subscriptions). etc etc. This is a complex topic.